# Access element name (no value) from array with javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my question is bad. I'm stuck in the following simple javascript code:

```
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25};

for (x in person)
{
document.write(person[x] + " ");
}
```

The above code result is :  John Doe 25

How do you show only value from `lname` element ? (with `for (... in ...)` statement)

I don't want to use `person={"John","Doe",25}` instead of one of above. I want to know how to access the element from array to get value.

Thank you

Edit: Thanks all for responses. This question was created because I have many items in array like :

```
        [{Name="A 1", Email="a1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group1"},
        {Name="A 2", Email="a2@manufacturer.com", Group="Group2"},
        {Name="A 3", Email="a3@manufacturer.com", Group="Group3"},
        {Name="B 1", Email="b1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group1"},
        {Name="V 1", Email="b1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group2"},
        {Name="X 1", Email="b1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group4"},
        {Name="Y 1", Email="b1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group3"},
        {Name="Z 1", Email="b1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group3"},
        {Name="W 1", Email="b1@manufacturer.com", Group="Group6"}]
```

I want to iterate this array and compare the element with my owned value.
`if object1.Group == 'Group3' { code }`

Comment: Do you mean using `person.lname`? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I want to write lname on the page... for example `Doe` instead of `John Doe 25`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here is not an array, it is a JavaScript object. (In simple terms,) Arrays have numeric indexes, while objects have properties with property-name and value pairs.

To access a specific object property like "lname" simply say:

```
person.lname
// OR
person["lname"]
```

Or, if the name of the property you want to use is in a variable:

```
var whichProp = "lname";
person[whichProp]
```

With your data, to produce the output "John Doe" you'd say:

```
document.write(person.fname + " " + person.lname);
```

The `for (x in person)` syntax that you were using loops through every property of the `person` object, setting `x` to each property name in turn.

**UPDATE** FOR YOUR UPDATED QUESTION:

Assuming you have an array of objects:

```
var people = [{Name:"A 1", Email:"a1@manufacturer.com", Group:"Group1"},
              {Name:"A 2", Email:"a2@manufacturer.com", Group:"Group2"},
              {Name:"A 3", Email:"a3@manufacturer.com", Group:"Group3"},
              // etc ];
```

And you want to find the element where Group is "Group3" then you loop through the array with a traditional for loop as follows:

```
for (var i=0; i < people.length; i++) {
   if (people[i]["Group"] === "Group3") {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Within the if statement you can add a `break` statement if you want to stop processing after the first match. And of course you are free to use the `people[i].Group` syntax rather than `people[i]["Group"]` if you prefer it.

(Note also that your object literal syntax was incorrect in your question update: where you've used `=` you should've used `:` as shown in my answer above.)

Comment: Good explanation of all cases. @Michael See my example if you want to have an array of multiple person objects

Comment: What happens if I want to iterate the big array (see edited code above) and compare element ?

Comment: @MichaelSwan - I've updated my answer to cover your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25};
arr.push(person);

for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
   document.write(arr[i].lname+ " ");
}
```

**Update**

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UQXxz/)

Comment: @MichaelSwan could you solve your problem then or is further assistance needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the two properties `fname`, `lname` of the `person` object like this:

```
document.write(person.fname + " " + person.lname);
```

Comment: @MichaelSwan the code above assuming that the person is an array, if it is not an array try it without an index like  : `person.fname`, `person.lname` see my edit

Answer (score 1):

That's not an Array, that's an Object.  If you know the property you want to access, you don't need to iterate the Object. Just reference the property directly.

```
person.lname;
```

**Edit:** To iterate your Array and take action when the group matches:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (objects[i].Group == "Group3") {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

But, the code you posted is invalid. Property/value pairs are separated with a `:`, not `=`.